# Will deja dup or any other backup program work with Charter Cloud Drive?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, backup, deja-dup

Charter Communications offers their own cloud drive backup service for their customers.  Since it is unlimited disk space, I am considering using it.

Does deja dup or any other backup solution support this service?  I cannot seem to find an answer via Google or other search engine.  Hopefully someone has had experience here.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get all the necessary information from Charter Communications, you can accomplish it.  This statement is from the charter website:

***`"Charter Cloud Drive provides you with unlimited storage space and is accessed through either http://clouddrive.charter.net (including by a Smartphone web browser) or desktop software."`***

Go into System Settings, and click on Backup.  That will bring up the backup interface.

Click on the Storage Tab,

[image]
and choose your Backup Location

[image]